# App is crashing because sender is unrecognized

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, crash

Here is the code where I add recognizers to all images in viewController

```
    var index = 0
    for imageView in imageViews {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.openImageGallery(_:)))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.tag = index
        index = index + 1
    }
```

And here is my method that gets triggered

```
@objc private func openImageGallery(_ sender: UIImageView) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum) {
        Alertift.actionSheet(message: nil)
            .actions(["Choose Image", "Remove"])
            .action(.cancel("Cancel"))
            .finally { action, index in
                if action.style == .cancel {
                    return
                }
                if index == 0 {
                    self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                if index == 1 {
                    print(sender.tag)
                }
            }
            .show()
    }
}
```

So what happens here is, user taps on a imageView and action sheet opens. It has 2 options. Remove option is something I am interested in. I want to erase an image in imageView that is tapped a moment before.

I figured I can use tags but it's not working. App crashes. Any ideas?

```
2018-05-12 16:52:32.645088+0300 Lez[6027:2387148] *** Terminating app 

due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c03e0200'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1839e2d8c 0x182b9c5ec 0x1839f0098 0x1839e85c8 0x1838ce41c 0x10501bd78 0x104fdfe84 0x1057fe4a4 0x1057ff9c0 0x10580e518 0x1057fd050 0x105807a98 0x1057fef88 0x1057fce90 0x18d79e0c0 0x18dbb5eec 0x18d7aa3cc 0x18da3bcbc 0x18d5adc04 0x18d5ad7ac 0x18d5ad134 0x18d697048 0x18d6970e8 0x187b68774 0x108ea1220 0x108ea5db0 0x18398b070 0x183988bc8 0x1838a8da8 0x18588b020 0x18d88978c 0x105030178 0x183339fc0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 4):

In your action function you have an incorrect argument type, it has to be a `UIGestureRecognizer` object. Fix it like this:

```
@objc private func openImageGallery(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Your code
}
```

You could't call `tag` property because gesture recognizers don't have such one. You have to refer it's `view` property to achieve goal:

```
print(sender.view!.tag)
```

Comment: Actually I did that and error stated that UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't have a tag. But I managed to get it to work.

Comment: @Kira watch the second code snippet. We do not call tag on GR, we call it on it's view.